# Ruby gem for generating content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

Is there a gem for generating content, what I am trying to do is get gem that will generate random:

- sentences (with cca. word count)
- numbers
- paragraphs
- etc.

Seems simple enough but I cannot seems to find anything, there is `lorem-impsum-me` gem but I would like something better than that. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faker does what you are needing, I think. It'll do paragraphs, words, addresses, name, emails, etc.

http://faker.rubyforge.org/

Comment: No problem! It is a really fun Gem to use. I love the names it comes up with :)